# Wireless headphones on a MacBook running 10.4 — Does Bluetooth work?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, headphones

Can MacBooks (10.4) stream music to Bluetooth headphones? If not, is my only other option to purchase bulky/expensive wireless headphones, or is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bluetooth profile necessary for stereo audio, [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A2DP#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29), is [supported by OS X since version 10.5](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071027122258725) (aka “Leopard”). As you use 10.4 (aka “Tiger”), the answer to the first part of your question is:

**Bluetooth audio only works in 64 kbit/s mono quality via the [headset profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A2DP#Headset_Profile_.28HSP.29) in 10.4.**

Probably not what you want for music listening, even if the headphones support it. As to the second part of your question:

**You are stuck with wireless solutions working via the audio jack, USB or FireWire.**

In the case of USB / FW solutions (if such wireless solutions exist), check these for 10.4 compatibility before you invest.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, Bluetooth works. Take a look a [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000F0A5UU) :) A bit expensive, but I'm sure there are a lot of alternatives around.

Comment: OP is on 10.4. A2DP was added in 10.5. See my answer – essentially, for OP, Bluetooth music does **not** work.

Comment: Ok, my honnest mistake. You were right!